# How to read a block in a storage pool (zpool) using dd?

Tags: solaris, zfs

I want to read a block in zpool storage pool using dd command. Since zpool doesn't create a device file like other volume manager like vxvm. I dunno which block device to use for reading. Is there any way to read block by block data in zpool ?

Answer (score 1):

No idea about what might be useful doing so but you certainly can read blocks in the underlying devices used by the pool. They are shown by the `zpool status` command. If you are really asking about zvols instead of zpools, they are accessible under /dev/zvol/rdsk/pool-name/zvol-name. If you want to look at internal zpool data, you probably want to use zdb.

Comment: I want to take a backup image of zpool to a vxvm volume.

Comment: A prerequisite would be to export the pool, i.e. unmount all file systems and zfs volumes, during the whole backup time. That might be unacceptable as a backup strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the zdb command. Here is a pdf about it, and the help output.

http://www.bruningsystems.com/osdevcon_draft3.pdf

```
# zdb --help

zdb: illegal option -- -
Usage: zdb [-CumdibcsDvhL] poolname [object...]
   zdb [-div] dataset [object...]
   zdb -m [-L] poolname [vdev [metaslab...]]
   zdb -R poolname vdev:offset:size[:flags]
   zdb -S poolname
   zdb -l [-u] device
   zdb -C

Dataset name must include at least one separator character '/' or '@'
If dataset name is specified, only that dataset is dumped
If object numbers are specified, only those objects are dumped

Options to control amount of output:
    -u uberblock
    -d dataset(s)
    -i intent logs
    -C config (or cachefile if alone)
    -h pool history
    -b block statistics
    -m metaslabs
    -c checksum all metadata (twice for all data) blocks
    -s report stats on zdb's I/O
    -D dedup statistics
    -S simulate dedup to measure effect
    -v verbose (applies to all others)
    -l dump label contents
    -L disable leak tracking (do not load spacemaps)
    -R read and display block from a device

Below options are intended for use with other options (except -l):
    -A ignore assertions (-A), enable panic recovery (-AA) or both (-AAA)
    -F attempt automatic rewind within safe range of transaction groups
    -U <cachefile_path> -- use alternate cachefile
    -X attempt extreme rewind (does not work with dataset)
    -e pool is exported/destroyed/has altroot/not in a cachefile
    -p <path> -- use one or more with -e to specify path to vdev dir
    -P print numbers parsable
    -t <txg> -- highest txg to use when searching for uberblocks
Specify an option more than once (e.g. -bb) to make only that option verbose
Default is to dump everything non-verbosely
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it.

```
# zdb
tank:
    version: 28
    name: 'tank'
    ...
    vdev_tree:
    ...
    children[0]:
    ...
        children[0]:
    ...
            path: '/dev/label/bank1d1'
            phys_path: '/dev/label/bank1d1'

    ...
```

So I took the array indexes 0 0 to get my first disk (bank1d1) and did this command. It did something. I don't know how to read the output.

zdb -R tank 0:0:4e00:200 | strings

Have fun... try not to destroy anything. Here is your warning from the man page:

```
The  zdb  command is used by support engineers to diagnose failures and
gather statistics. Since the ZFS file system is  always  consistent  on
disk  and is self-repairing, zdb should only be run under the direction
by a support engineer.
```

And please tell us what you actually were looking for. Was Alan right that you wanted to do backups?

Answer (score 1):

You can read from underlying raw devices in the pool, but as far as I can tell there's no concept of single contiguous block device representing the whole pool.
The pool in ZFS is not a single contiguous block of sectors that 'classic' volume managers are. ZFS internal structure is closer to a tree which would be somewhat challenging to represent as a flat array of blocks.

[Ben Rockwood's blog post "zdb: Examining ZFS At Point-Blank Range"](https://cuddletech.com/?p=407) may help getting better idea of what's under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup ZFS filesystems you should be using the following tools:

- 'zfs snapshot' to create a stable snapshot of the filesystem
- 'zfs send' to send a copy of the snapshot to somewhere else
- 'zfs receive' to go back from a snapshot to a filesystem.

'dd' is almost certainly *not* the tool you should be using.  In your case you could 'zfs send' and redirect the output into a file on your other filesystem.

See [chapter 7 of the ZFS administration guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gavvx/index.html) for more details.